# Segmentation fault issue using the QB64 function SWAP with user-defined types

Tags: qb64

I was trying to compile the QB program DIMORDIN.BAS (an example contained into the old QB4.5 package) using QB64 V1.2.

The compilation doesn't indicate errors, but the execution of the program shown a surprise ... The execution of the most of sort types result in a segmentation fault.

Debugging the code I discovered that the cause of this result is the language function `SWAP` that, on evidence, is not able to swap complex and/or user defined types. Lines such this: `SWAP MatrOrd(Riga), MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto)` gives segmentation fault.

Have you a solution? Why is QB64 not compliant with this feature of QB4.5?

The following code is the original code of a SUB that gives segmentation fault(unluckely I've only the italian version).

I cannot post here the full code because it's greater than 30,000 chars.

```
SUB OrdShell STATIC

    ' Imposta lo scarto per il confronto a met del numero di record in MatrOrd:
    Scarto = RigheMass \ 2

    PRINT
    DO WHILE Scarto > 0 ' Cicla finch Scarto non diventa zero.
        Limite = RigheMass - Scarto
        DO
            Scambi = FALSO ' Presume non vi siano stati scambi
            ' con questo valore di Scarto.

            ' Confronta elementi e scambia quelli non in ordine:
            FOR Riga = 1 TO Limite
                IF MatrOrd(Riga).Lung > MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto).Lung THEN
                    SWAP MatrOrd(Riga), MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto)
                    ScambiaBarre Riga, Riga + Scarto
                    Scambi = Riga
                END IF
            NEXT Riga

            ' Al passaggio successivo ordina solo fino al punto dell'ultimo
            ' scambio:
            Limite = Scambi - Scarto
        LOOP WHILE Scambi

        ' Nessuno scambio al precedente valore di scarto; lo dimezza:
        Scarto = Scarto \ 2
    LOOP
END SUB
```

To help you understanting the SUB I add the declarative portion of the program:

```
' Definisce il tipo di dati usato per contenere i dati delle barre:
TYPE TipoOrd
    Lung AS INTEGER ' Lunghezza della barra (l'elemento di
    ' confronto nei vari ordinamenti)
    ValColore AS INTEGER ' Colore della barra
    StringaBarra AS STRING * 43 ' La barra (una stringa di 43 caratteri)
END TYPE

' Dichiara le costanti globali:
CONST FALSO = 0, VERO = NOT FALSO, COLONNASIN = 49
CONST NUMOPZIONI = 11, NUMORDINAMENTI = 6

' Dichiara le variabili globali e alloca loro spazio nella memoria. MatrOrd
' e BackupOrd sono matrici del tipo di dati TipoOrd definito sopra:
DIM SHARED MatrOrd(1 TO 43) AS TipoOrd, BackupOrd(1 TO 43) AS TipoOrd
DIM SHARED LeggendaOpzioni(1 TO NUMOPZIONI) AS STRING * 14
DIM SHARED TempoIniz AS SINGLE
DIM SHARED PrimoPiano, Sfondo, Silenzio, Pausa
DIM SHARED Selezione, RigheMass, RigheIniz, ColoriMass
```

I've written the following small code to demonstrate the issue that the function `SWAP` generates:

```
$CONSOLE:ONLY
_DEST _CONSOLE

TYPE TipoOrd
    Lung AS INTEGER ' Lunghezza della barra (l'elemento di
    ' confronto nei vari ordinamenti)
    ValColore AS INTEGER ' Colore della barra
    StringaBarra AS STRING * 43 ' La barra (una stringa di 43 caratteri)
END TYPE

DIM a(1 TO 43) AS TipoOrd

a(1).Lung = 2: a(2).Lung = 4
PRINT a(1).Lung, a(2).Lung
SWAP a(1), a(2)
PRINT a(1).Lung, a(2).Lung

END
```

Comment: The line under your swap **ScambiaBarre Riga, Riga + Scarto** what does that do?

Comment: @eoredson,  That line call a SUB that swaps two lines of chars on the screen. But it doesn't contains problems. I verified the error using gdb. In my self-answer I solved the issue using an opportune SUB to swap `TipoOrd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this QB64 v1.3a code for swapping structures with some success:

```
TYPE Struct1
    Element1 AS INTEGER
    Element2 AS INTEGER
END TYPE
DIM SHARED StructA(10) AS Struct1
DIM SHARED StructB(10) AS Struct1
StructA(1).Element1 = -1
StructB(1).Element1 = 1
PRINT "StructA="; StructA(1).Element1
PRINT "StructB="; StructB(1).Element1
PRINT "Swap:"
SWAP StructA(1), StructB(1)
PRINT "StructA="; StructA(1).Element1
PRINT "StructB="; StructB(1).Element1
END
```

Comment: I am using QB64 v1.3

Comment: Ok! Your program runs also with my QB64 environment on Linux (CPU AMD 64). But I tryed to simplify my code and the issue persists. (See the new edit I made at the end of my question)

Comment: Ok! With the v1.3 there's no more the issue I had!

Comment: Hi, I confirmed valid your reply, but It's not true if you don't specify in the answer that you used the version 1.3! I tried to edit your answer, but @tanveerbadar rejected it. (However I didn't verify if QB64 1.2 with different compiler setups is able to compile)

Answer (score 1):

After a coffee I solved the problem writing the subroutine `SWAPT` that performs the swap between variables of user-defined type `TipoOrd`.

After I substitute the  `SWAP` function with the `SWAPT` subroutine, the program correctly run.

However the issue about the non compliance between QB64 e QB4.5 remains.

Here the modified function and `SWAPT` subroutine:

```
SUB OrdShell STATIC

    ' Imposta lo scarto per il confronto a met del numero di record in MatrOrd:
    Scarto = RigheMass \ 2

    PRINT
    DO WHILE Scarto > 0 ' Cicla finch Scarto non diventa zero.
        Limite = RigheMass - Scarto
        DO
            Scambi = FALSO ' Presume non vi siano stati scambi
            ' con questo valore di Scarto.

            ' Confronta elementi e scambia quelli non in ordine:
            FOR Riga = 1 TO Limite
                IF MatrOrd(Riga).Lung > MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto).Lung THEN
                    REM SWAP MatrOrd(Riga), MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto)                             
                    SWAPT MatrOrd(Riga), MatrOrd(Riga + Scarto)

                    ScambiaBarre Riga, Riga + Scarto
                    Scambi = Riga
                END IF
            NEXT Riga

            ' Al passaggio successivo ordina solo fino al punto dell'ultimo
            ' scambio:
            Limite = Scambi - Scarto
        LOOP WHILE Scambi

        ' Nessuno scambio al precedente valore di scarto; lo dimezza:
        Scarto = Scarto \ 2
    LOOP
END SUB

SUB SWAPT (a AS TipoOrd, b AS TipoOrd)
    SWAP a.Lung, b.Lung
    SWAP a.ValColore, b.ValColore
    SWAP a.StringaBarra, b.StringaBarra
END SUB
```